# Helm completion no longer used for M-x or find-file

Tags: helm

Tonight I started Emacs, and `helm-mode` is no longer used for certain actions. So far I have found that, for me, `M-x` and `find-file` don't use `helm` anymore, which they have since I first started using helm. I can clearly see `Helm` displayed in my mode-line, but when I hit `M-x` or `C-x C-f`, `Helm` disappears from my mode-line.

For me these have always worked automatically, I haven't configured these commands to use `helm` explicitly. Other commands continue to use `helm`, e.g., `describe-variable` and `describe-function` still use `helm` for completion.

Normally, I would assume that I messed up my configuration file or that an update to `helm` changed something. However, all my configuration files are under version control, and nothing has changed. Also, I think I might have updated `helm` yesterday through MELPA, but I can't imagine that I would have gone all day without using `find-file` or `M-x` without noticing that they had changed. Also, on the [`helm` github page](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), I cannot see any indication that these things have been changed recently.

Starting Emacs with the `-Q` option to bypass my init file, activating packages with `package-initialize` and running `M-x helm-mode` to activate `helm` gives me the same results: `helm` completion is used for e.g., `describe-variable` and `describe-function`, but not for `M-x` or `find-file` other commands might be affected as well, but this is what I have found so far. Is anyone else experiencing this behavior? Does anyone know what is going on?

To be clear, `helm-find-files` and `helm-M-x` commands still work, so I could bind them to `C-x C-f` and `M-x`, but I am curious what happened, to the previoius behavior.

Comment: As your configuration is under version control, you can trivially revert your package update, and compare.

Comment: @phils my packages are the one thing that is not under version control, but I will probably be changing this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is done in [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/1de1701c73b15a86e99ab1c5c53bd0e8659d8ede) by the helm maintainer to reduce confusion for new users, if you want the old behaviour, just undo that commit by customizing `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`.

Comment: Haha, yeah...the commit message is: "Unhelmize find-file and M-x by default to avoid confusion." I actually scanned the changes in the code of the commit right before that, and then stopped looking. Thanks!