# How to restore helm's old behavior?

Tags: helm

Since a couple of months ago, Helm has changed in his behavior of *"doing its thing"* when some command requires selecting a candidate, which was a default behavior in old releases of Helm. How can I restore that in these new releases of Helm?

Edit: the referred old behavior is that one where Helm handles completion candidates for any given command that requires choosing one candidate.

Comment: The question as it stands is unclear. Please edit it to explain in more detail what helm behavior you want to achieve and what you see instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behavior of helm has changed recently. See [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/1de1701c73b15a86e99ab1c5c53bd0e8659d8ede). I think what you are experiencing is the same thing I asked about [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19528/helm-completion-no-longer-used-for-m-x-or-find-file).

My solution was to add the commands that used to "do their thing" (i.e., use helm completion) to the `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19529). For example, to get `find-file` to use hem completion again:

```
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(find-file . helm-completing-read-symbols))
```